# meaning of -h in ls command

Tags: ls

```
[root@pdbosl02 daily]# ls -lrth
total 12G
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 3.8G Dec  7 20:43 BKPOSLPRD_jcns9p1f.F_bkp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 4.2G Dec  7 20:46 BKPOSLPRD_jdns9p1f.F_bkp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 3.0G Dec  7 20:51 BKPOSLPRD_jbns9p1f.F_bkp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 140M Dec  7 20:52 ALG_OSLPRD_jgns9rfr.alg
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 189M Dec  7 20:52 ALG_OSLPRD_jfns9rfr.alg
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 202M Dec  7 20:52 ALG_OSLPRD_jens9rfr.alg
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba  42M Dec  7 20:52 c-4249173797-20121207-00
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba  41M Dec  7 20:52 ctrl_071223
```

I want to know about `h` in `ls -lrth` command.

Comment: `man ls` will give you your answer. It clearly says *print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)*

Comment: This http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls+-lrth is even better

Answer (score 5):

from `man ls` (on a Gnu system, but `-h` is not available in all `ls`s)

```
-h, --human-readable
              with  -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K
              234M 2G)
```

Meaning that it will display file sizes using K, M, G postfixes: 1K = 1024, 1M = 1024K, 1G = 1024M (all in bytes). see http://www.athropolis.com/popup/c-comp2.htm

This is very similar to how the metric (SI) system works ( 1000μ = 1m, 1000m = 1, 1K = 1000, 1M = 1000K, 1G = 1000M ) however the metric si system uses a factor of 1000 = 10³ = 10×10×10, and the computer system uses a factor of 1024 = 2¹⁰ = 2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2. (Use `ls --si` to show in powers of 1000.)

### Side note

This can be confusing so a new naming system was invented so 1Ki = 1024, 1Mi = 1024Ki, 1Gi = 1024Mi. Unfortunately these are not used much. They do appear in the ls manual, but not in its usage. It uses the names without the i.

Comment: Note that [there is no "_the_" `ls` manual](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433045/possible-versions-of-ls/433056#comment781981_433056) and this answer is peculiar to the couple of `ls` commands that actually _have_ an `--si` option.  Several have `-h` and no `--si`, and the two that have (see commentary at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435123/) differ on what `-h` and `--si` actually output, although one wouldn't know it purely from their manuals alone.