# Does option "-h" for "ls" display size in MB or MiB and is it consistent over Unix-based systems?

Tags: ls, size

The usual `ls` command can display the size of files with the option `-h` and I am having a little doubt about it being display in [MB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) or [MIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

For example :

```
$ ls -lha
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4.0K Apr  2 21:49 . 
drwxr-xr-x 5 user group 4.0K Apr  2 21:49 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 129M Apr  2 21:49 2018-04-02T21:49:08.981976.hdf5
```

So, this leaves me with 2 questions :

- Does `ls -lha` displayed the size in MB or MiB?
- Is it consistent across Unix-based operating systems and their own versions over time?

N.B.: Not only commercial Unix-based operating systems should be considered for this question.

Comment: I am not asking about the meaning but a subtle difference (which stay "blurry" in these answers's posts) in one option of this command, not to mention whether if this option display is consistent across OSs.

Comment: None of the Q&As pointed to by don_crissti actually answers _this_ question, which is _not_ what the option does, but whether the units are consistent across all implementations and what they are.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293043/22222) from the duplicate answer your question about the units? If you are primarily interested in whether `-h` is portable ([it isn't](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html)), then please [edit] your question to reflect that. Editing will also put it into the reopen review queue.

Comment: It doesn't, terdon.  The giveaway is it talking about a `--si` option as if that were a universal, and it speaking of "_the_" `ls` manual ([a familiar turn of phrase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433045/possible-versions-of-ls/433056#comment781981_433056)).  Two non-GNU `ls` programs with `-h` options, completely unaddressed by answers here or there, have already been mentioned in comments on this very page.

Comment: @JdeBP the question of what the `-h` flag does in GNU `ls`, which actually has it, has been adequately answered by the dupe. I don't know how these `ls` you mention should be "addressed", we can't give a list of all `ls` implementations, that would be off topic. Paradox, again, please edit your question and clarify what you're asking. The `-h` option is not standard so yes, it can behave differently or be absent or do something completely different if the authors of an implementation choose it.

Comment: Addressing the other `ls` implementations that exist apart from the GNU one is _off-topic_?  I strongly dispute that.  This is Unix and Linux Stack Exchange, not GNU Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JdeBP of course non-GNU is 100% on topic! What is off topic is asking or providing a long list that attempts to cover all current and past implementations of `ls` in the \*nix world. If Paradox would only edit the question to make it ask something that is specific and answerable about the portability of `-h`, then it would absolutely be on topic. But asking for the existence and behavior of the `-h` flag on every `ls` in existence is just too broad for this site.

Answer (score 10):

From the ls manpage:

```
-h, --human-readable
         with -l and -s, print sizes like 1K 234M 2G etc.
--si   likewise, but use powers of 1000 not 1024
```

So if you just use -h you will get MiB (^1024). If you add --si to the options, it will use MB (^1000). Verified on ubuntu, debian, and redhat. I don't have access to any commercial UNIX operating systems at the moment, but out of the box they tend not to include a -h option.

Comment: "but out of the box they tend not to include a -h option" From my experience, it is exactly the opposite (Fedora, Manjaro, Debian, Ubuntu and Scientific Linux) ; maybe you meant something else?

Comment: None of those are commercial Unices.  Although M. McMahon could at least have looked at the BSDs.

Comment: @JdeBP This option was available on the version of RHEL 6/7 I had been using in the past. (BTW Scientific Linux is based on it). But, still, I do not see the point : are "commercial Unices" universally lacking this option?

Comment: Solaris has it, not AIX or HPUX.  I recall answering this, but don't see it readily.

Comment: @ThomasDickey - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302681/22142

Comment: @Paradox none of the systems you have mentioned are Unix, commercial or otherwise. The `-h` option [is not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) so you cannot depend on its working anywhere. GNU `ls` has it, yes, so any Linux system will have it, but Unices can do as they wish.